# Significato di "taroccare" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel racconto *I ventitré giorni della città di Alba*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> In quel medesimo giorno, a Dogliani ch’è un grosso paese a venti chilometri da Alba, c’era la fiera autunnale e in piazza ci sarà stato un migliaio di partigiani che sparavano nei tirasegni, **taroccavano** le ragazze, bevevano le bibite e riuscivano con molta facilità a non sentire il fragore della battaglia di Alba.

Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "taroccare" in questa frase? Ho cercato questo verbo in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nessuna accezione che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taroccare in questo contesto mi sembra voglia dire fare la corte, corteggiare , “tacchinare”.

Nell’articolo [Voce del verbo “taroccare”, spiegato dall’Accademia della Crusca](https://www.linkiesta.it/it/article/2017/01/14/voce-del-verbo-taroccare-spiegato-dallaccademia-della-crusca/32931/) si può trovare la seguente spiegazione.

> In principio significava “praticare il gioco dei tarocchi”, o anche
>   “corteggiare una donna”. Poi ha assunto il significato che gli diamo
>   oggi

e più avanti si può leggere:

> il terzo significato è segnalato come regionalismo, 'corteggiare una
>   donna', dal piemontese tarôché 'amoreggiare';

Comment: Giusto! E sottolineerei che in quella pagina della Crusca spiegano che il senso di “corteggiare” viene proprio da un uso piemontese, come è Fenoglio.